# imdecode returns None Python opencv2

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv

Look at this code,

```
img = cv2.imread("image2.jpg",0)
img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1] #Encodes and stores in buffer
print(img_str)

#for i,item in enumerate(img_str):    }  THIS
 #   img_str[i] = 255-item            }  IS CONFUSING

nparr = np.frombuffer(img_str, np.uint8)
img2 = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

My question is without this,

```
#for i,item in enumerate(img_str):    }  THIS
 #   img_str[i] = 255-item            }  IS CONFUSING
```

The code runs fine imdecode returns the same! But however when I uncomment it imdecode returns **None**

[Opencv docs say](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode)

> If the buffer is too short or contains invalid data, the empty matrix/image is returned.

What exactly is the invalid data that makes imdecode return none? Or any other mistake?

Comment: so you read the image as a greyscale(1 channel), encoded it and then decode it as color image (3 channels) probably the data that is trying to read and can't because the encoded one is lacking 2 channels is this "invalid data". Maybe I am mistaken, since I have not use it this way, but try to put the same flag

Comment: But without that for loop everything runs fine! No error.. just when I subtract each number in array from 255 (Again array looks same..values are within range 255) Why can't imdecode work now? any valid reason? is i'm asking

Comment: @api55 Just adding 1 to every item makes imdecode not work..I don't understand why

Comment: take a look to the answer, I tried to explain it as thoroughly as possible :)

Comment: @api55 Thank you so much for the time you spent ! i'll take a look

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I misunderstood your question before, but now your comments make it clearer.

When you [encode an image in '.jpg'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) it is **not a pixel array** as before, but an array of bytes that represents a jpeg image. It will be the equivalent to read the bytes of the image directly with native functions.

If you transform each byte, it won't be able to decode it correctly, and your data will be invalid.

Let's examine the data a little bit more carefully:

First, we load the image and encode the data

```
# Exactly what you have to load and encode
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("image2.jpg",0)
img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1]
```

Now, lets flatten the image array and see the first 10 pixels ( I use a random image I had in my drive):

```
img.flatten()[0:10]
```

This gives me:

```
[191, 191, 191, 191, 191, 191, 191, 191, 191, 191]
```

Now, lets show the first 10 bytes of the encoded one:

```
print(img_str.flatten()[0:10])
```

And I get:

```
[255 216 255 224   0  16  74  70  73  70]
```

As you can see, it is totally different numbers as before.... and not only that, At least the 2 first bytes gives information about the image as it is explain in the link I put a little before.

Start of image is the following code:

```
0xFF, 0xD8
```

That if you put it in decimal numbers it will give you:

```
255 216
```

Which is the first 2 bytes of the byte array... If you subtract `255-byte` for all bytes, then the initial part will be `0 39` which will be an invalid syntax for the decoder to parse it.

In conclusion, do not change the image bytes after encoding it, change them before encoding it if needed, and try to also use OpenCV's function or from numpy to do it faster, the loop takes quite long in python. To invert the image and then encode it is the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image2.jpg",0)
invImg = cv2.bitwise_not(img) # equivalent to 255-img
img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', invImg )[1] 
img2 = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Another thing to consider, if you have an image and encode it and decode it in jpg, it **WON'T BE THE SAME IMAGE**, because jpg is a lossy compression, and it will have some small differences.